# SpringBoot Admin - How to prevent SpringBoot Admin Server to register itself?

Tags: java, spring-boot-admin

Small question regarding Spring Boot Admin (SBA) please.

I can register clients to SBA Server fine, very happy.
Unfortunately, the server itself registers to itself.

The usage of SBA is to monitor and have information on the SBA clients.
I am having a hard time getting the SBA Server to not register itself, but just accepting registrations from clients.

What is the best way to achieve this please?

In my app, I am having:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your admin server properties, you can either use `spring.boot.admin.discovery.services` property to specifically whitelist applications that you would like to monitor, or, you can use `spring.boot.admin.discovery.ignored-services` property to blacklist any application you don't want to monitor.

In your case, you can do:

```
spring.boot.admin.discovery.ignored-services:
  - 'admin-server'
```

where admin-server is `spring.application.name` of your admin server.

Checkout [Table 4. Discovery configuration options](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#_converting_serviceinstances).